# Uploadcollection sending files but can't be opened?

Tags: javascript, file, sapui5

Here is the thing. I'm trying to upload and send files from my app to a sap gateway by using UploadCollection sapui5 and a post request using ajax.

I was asked to send every single file in a xstring format (one by one), so the backend service can return a proper response.

This is how I'm trying to get the uploaded files content

```
new sap.m.UploadCollection({
                    id:                        'upFiles',
                    numberOfAttachmentsText:   'Adjuntar archivos',
                    showSeparators:            'All',
                    fileType:                  ['jpg','jpeg','png','pdf','ods','pptx','xlsm','docx','doc', 'odt', 'docm','ppt','xlsx','rar','zip'], 
                    noDataText:                'No se han cargado archivos todavia',
                    class:                     'docpago-upload',
                    uploadUrl:                 '/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZGWRE_WF_FILES_SRV/WfFileCollectionSet',
                    maximumFilenameLength:     120,
                    maximumFileSize:           10,
                    multiple:                  true,
                    uploadEnabled:             true,
                    terminationEnabled:        true,
                    change: function(oEvent) {

                        var file = oEvent.getParameter("files");
                        var numfiles = oEvent.getParameter("files").length;
}
});
```

And this is how I'm trying to send files through an ajax post request

```
                                                jQuery.ajax({
                                                    url: sUrlUpload,
                                                    type: "POST",
                                                    data: file, //Files I want to send
                                                    contentType: "application/json",
                                                    datatype : "text",
                                                    headers: {
                                                        'X-CSRF-Token': token, //token generated to send request
                                                        'slug': slug  //a parameter I need to do some stuff
                                                    },
                                                    success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                                                        console.log('Uploaded files: ' + JSON.stringify(data));


                                                    },
                                                    error: function(oError) {
                                                        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(oError.responseText))
                                                    }
                                                });
```

For some reason, In the sap gateway side, files are successfully uploaded but not even single one can be open because the programs say "invalid format", "corrupted file" etc etc. And I think is because I'm not passing the file's content in a proper way. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How does your MGW_APPL_SRV_RUNTIME~CREATE_STREAM implementation looks like?

Should be something like this:

```
  METHOD /IWBEP/IF_MGW_APPL_SRV_RUNTIME~CREATE_STREAM.
    DATA: ls_key_tab                   TYPE /iwbep/s_mgw_name_value_pair,
          lt_key_tab                   TYPE /iwbep/t_mgw_name_value_pair,
          ls_document                  TYPE <YOUR TABLE>,
          lv_documentid                TYPE char100.

    CASE iv_entity_name.
      WHEN '<YOUR ENTITY NAME>'.
        READ TABLE it_key_tab WITH KEY name = 'DocumentId' INTO ls_key_tab.

        ls_document-documentid = ls_key_tab-value.
        ls_document-mimetype = is_media_resource-mime_type.
        ls_document-filename = iv_slug.
        ls_document-value = is_media_resource-value.
        ls_document-sydate = sy-datum.
        ls_document-sytime  = sy-uzeit.
        DELETE FROM <YOUR TABLE> WHERE documentid = ls_document-documentid.
        INSERT INTO <YOUR TABLE> VALUES ls_document.

        fileupdset_get_entity(
          EXPORTING
            iv_entity_name     = iv_entity_name
            iv_entity_set_name = iv_entity_set_name
            iv_source_name     = iv_source_name
            it_key_tab         = it_key_tab
            it_navigation_path = it_navigation_path
          IMPORTING
            er_entity          = ls_document ).

        copy_data_to_ref( EXPORTING is_data = ls_document
                          CHANGING  cr_data = er_entity ).
    ENDCASE.

  ENDMETHOD.
```

On your table you should have a field, something like DocumentId that will serve as primary key.

You can then call the url "/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZGWRE_WF_FILES_SRV/WfFileCollectionSet('DocumentIdHere')"

To retrieve the file you can simply make a GET request to the url "/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZGWRE_WF_FILES_SRV/WfFileCollectionSet('DocumentIdHere')/$value"

Good examples [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/09/23/file-uploaddownload-through-netweaver-gateway/) and [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/24/uploading-files-to-sap-gw-downloading-files-from-sap-gw-new-techniques/). Hope that helps!